# Can't connect to my server via ssl from let'sencrypt

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, nginx, react-native, lets-encrypt

I've a Ruby on Rails Server with nginx as a web server, and have a mobile application which connects to the server over ssl (Free certificate from let's encrypt), the application is working fine on iOS but on android on a certain devices when the application sends a request to the server the request doesn't reach the server, but some times it works. the weird thing is that i don't get any errors.

my nginx configurations

```
listen 443 ssl default_server;
listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_ciphers EECDH+AES128:RSA+AES128:EECDH+AES256:RSA+AES256:EECDH+3DES:RSA+3DES:!MD5;
ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
ssl_session_tickets off;
ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparam.pem;
ssl_session_timeout 1d;
```

i've found some issues talking about ssl error with android 7 but i've tried the solution and it didn't help

```
ssl_ecdh_curve prime256v1;
```

my application is built with React native and i'm using Frisbee package for http requests

any thoughts about how to solve this critical issue ?!

Comment: Since Nginx 1.11.0 and OpenSSL 1.0.2 one can specify multiple ciphers like so: `ssl_ecdh_curve prime256v1:secp384r1;` - see nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_ecdh_curve